# restore postgresql on pythonanywhere from sql-format dump

Tags: postgresql, psql, restore

I upgraded PythonAnywhere to the $99 startup plan and created a PostgreSQL database. The PythonAnywhere database page shows:
`Address: magula6-1249.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com
Port: 11249 
Superuser role name: super`

I want to populate my new database from a pg-dump file created on my macbook.
I’ve tried several variations of:
`$ psql -H magula6-1249.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com -U super -p
11249 -f 2019_7_30_pgdump.sql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.11249"?`

I also tried: 
`postgres=# \i /home/magula6/cogswatch/2019_7_30_pgdump.sql
tpsql:/home/magula6/cogswatch/2019_7_30_pgdump.sql:149: ERROR:  function "function_correctiveaction" already exists with s
ame argument types`

Oddly the Pythonanywhere database page says: 
`Postgres disk usage:
100% full (1.0 GB of your 1.0 GB quota)` 

but the database appears empty:
`postgres=# \d
No relations found.`

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

`postgres=# grant usage on schema public to public;
postgres=# grant create on schema public to public;
postgres=# \d`

(all my tables appear - amazing)